# Replication from Enterprise to Standard edition

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

Can I define transactional replication while the Publisher and Distributor are both Enterprise Edition and the Subscriber is Standard Edition?

What do I need to consider in case it is possible (given I already know about partitioned tables)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can replicate from Enterprise edition to Standard edition.

The only caveat is Peer-to-Peer Replication requires all nodes to be Enterprise Edition, and Web and Express editions are Subscriber only.

[Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server - Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Replication)